# How can I schedule a Background Task to trigger at a specific time

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

This is a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I want to be able to trigger a task to execute at a specific time. My main concerns are accuracy, resource and user experience.
I have tried a TimeTrigger with an IBackgroundTask but found that, aside from the minimum 15 minutes constraint, the execution time is far from accurate - sometime the task triggers 8 minutes later, some times 20 so no use for a scheduled trigger.
I have looked at toast but I need the task to run without user input and, as far as I can see, the toast notifications have no capability to trigger code execution without the user interacting.
I have looked at the alarm clock approach but, firstly it uses toast notifications and, secondly, I understand you can only have one alarm app that the user must declare so that's a bit intrusive.
I have looked at using a Task.Delay approach using async and await to avoid blocking the UI thread but this is hardly a background-centric approach.
Has anyone managed to find a way to create resource-friendly, scheduled background tasks (i.e. an alarm and sleep function) for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: As far as I know Triggers are the only way to do this, but you're right they're inaccurate. I believe there's a minimum 30 minute time constraint but this can vary +/- 10 minutes or so. You seem to have done your homework - alarms, and toast notifications are other options, but these have their own drawbacks as you have pointed out. I think these are the only tools available to you...